# Сompetitive process using RabbitMQ and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, architecture, rabbitmq

I have distributed system, where exists service for order acceptance.
Incoming order is sent for all executors in the same time, but only one executor can accept this. For that purpose I use RabbitMQ and SQL server.

How to handle case, when two executors try to accept order at the same time?
Definitely I can set up transaction isolations in SQL Server, but what about Rabbit?

I know, this question is so broad, but I wonder how to handle that altogether?

Comment: Your title says MySQL, however, in your content and tags you reference SQL Server. Which are you *actually* using. Please update your post & tags, or subject appropriately as it's confusing for users at the moment.

Comment: Done, sorry, it is common question

Comment: The NServiceBus outbox feature is designed for exactly this scenario. It can be used to guarantee that a message and a database update is handled as an atomic operation – https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to handle case, when two executors try to accept order at the same time?
>   Definitely I can set up transaction isolations in SQL Server, but what about Rabbit?

Let SQL Server guarantee that at most one "executor" can accept an order.

You can let multiple sessions run a query like:

```
update orders
set state = 'ACCEPTED' 
output inserted.id, inserted.state 
where id=@ID and state ='NEW'
```

And only one will successfully update the order and return a row.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of RabbitMQ should be to send the message to a single consumer.   The only way I could think of to get your behavior is if you had configured [Topics](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html) instead of [work queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html).

Comment: Or if this person is using a `fanout` exchange. Either way, RMQ should be used as intended.